# How to Maximise Efficiency With hp12c gold calculator: Equation of Value Loan Schedule

Tags: analysis, finance

I would like to calculate the net present value of a loan schedule or an equation of value. e.g. "For an investor receives R1 000 after 2 years, R2 000 after 5 years and R4000 after 7 years, how much does he have to invest now at 10% p.a compound?"

I am looking for a faster way than to manually compute: 1000(1.1)^-2 + 2000(1.1)^-5 + 4000(1.1)^-7 = R4120.92

Isn't there a built-in sequence one can execute to come up with the present value at Time 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sequence for an hp12c

0 g CFj

1000 g CFj

0 g CFj

0 g CFj

2000 g CFj

0 g CFj

g CFj

4000 g CFj

10 i

f NPV

=4,120.92